# Skyrim for Xbox 360 glitches when I open menus inside of the game

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have been playing Skyrim for about two or three years now and it has been glitching since I got it.

When I open up any menus inside of the game (such as your personal inventory or the inventory of a chest etc), I must push the "Xbox guide" button twice before it will let me scroll through the inventory.

The only menus the glitch doesn't affect is the main Skyrim menu and when I'm speaking to somebody. Is there any way to fix this glitch or is it my game? Maybe my Xbox? It doesn't do this with any other games.

Answer (score -2):

Are your game discs scratched?

I've experienced similar issues with Call of Duty - it glitches out of the create class menu, and sooner or later it crashes my whole Xbox. I asked the GameStop guy he said it was the many scratches on the back.